# How can I programatically provide a specific transaction manager when calling a @Transactional annotated method

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

In my test I manually instantiate a class that is being `@Autowired` in production. I hand inject it with `@Autowired` dependencies. On this class I call a method that is annotated with `@Transactional` and downstream uses a `@PersistenceContext` annotated `EntitiyManager`. The error I get is

> No transaction aspect-managed TransactionStatus in scope

I would like to be able to programatically provide an `EntityManager` instance to be used by the context, but have no idea how to do this. Please advise. Also, please let me know if you need more background.

I am calling this `@Transactional` annotated method from my test from a `Callable` ran by an `ExecutorService` and therefore it has no access to `ThreadLocal`.

(Java 7 and Spring 4.1.1)

Comment: *I am calling this @Transactional annotated method from my test from a Callable ran by an ExecutorService and therefore it has no access to ThreadLocal* You always have access to ThreadLocal, you just need to define it yourself. However, ThreadLocal doesn't relate to your question at all.

Comment: I am calling the aforementioned method from a different thread than the one running the test. So yes, technically I have access to ThreadLocal, but it doesn't contain the transaction context.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `@Transactional`  you may use `@Transactional(value="myTransactionManager")`

Also have you `@Autowired` the `EntityManager` in your class? Can you provide the class code?

Answer (score 0):

Just get a working EM via `@Autowired` and set it where needed. Also check that your tests are marked as `@Transactional`.

Comment: I cannot since I call said `@Transactional` annotated method from a `Callable` from an `ExecutorService`. Therefore `ThreadLocal` is not available and that is why I ask for a **programmatic** solution.

Comment: Your problem is that the service you create is not proxied because it's not injected by spring. If you let Spring inject it in your test, you're good. It has nothing to do with your ExecutorService, because if you'd use the proxied bean there it would create a new session/tx (depending on the propagation, of course).

Comment: I have let Spring inject it and still have the same problem unfortunately. Let me stress yet again that the method is called from a different tread. :)